# How to have Nagstamon to mirror color alarms in Nagios

Tags: nagios, color

I wonder if there a way to mirror the color alarms that in Nagios to Nagstamon? 
For example  I have it setup when, I  set a critical alarm  that has been acknowledge, the color changes from red to blue.  Yet in Nagstamon it still remain red.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not. As you're probably aware, there's a "Colors" tab in the settings dialog that gives you the ability to change the colors for Ok, Warning, Crit, Uknown, Unreachable, Down, and Error.

Personally, I filter out acknowledged hosts and services, which you can do in the "Filters" tab of settings.